# Problem with the Flask API -- It returns only the last of the pages I try to scrape

Tags: python, api, flask

How can I make the API works for all the pages of the website which i want to scrape? Unfortunately, when I create the API, it returns only the last page. Without the API, it returns all the pages. Why is this happening? I probably need to insert a for loop but not sure! Thanks!

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scraper():
   pages=['', 'companies', 'universities', 'about-us', 'kickstart'] # different pages of the website i want to scrape
   for page in pages:
     page_link = 'http://www.xxxxxxx.org.uk/' + page
     page = urllib.request.urlopen(page_link ) 
     soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser') 
     for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()  
     text = soup.get_text()  # returns the text 
     lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())

     chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
     text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk) # cleans the texts from hrefs etc
 return text.encode('utf-8') # it works pretty well outside of the APP but when I create the API it returns only the last of the pages. 


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a variable before the for loop and append the results of each iteration to it, and then finally return that variable.

Your `text` variable gets overwritten in each iteration of the for loop.